# Onenote get page api issues

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

I have to read all pages from microsoft onenote irrespective of notebooks or sections. I am using GET https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/pages with valid access token.I am not getting page content in the response. How can I get content while fetching all pages.

Secondly if I try to get page content using content url specified in response the embedded images doesn't come as content but url to fetch that image. Thus to retrieve one page with 5 images let's say I need to make 7 calls.
1. To get all pages
2. To get each page content
3. TO get embedded images from content (here 5 in my case).

Is their any support for bulk operation ?

Is their any SDK for onenote for java integration ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get page content while fetching all pages.  You need to iterate through each page and fetch the content. This is by design.

There is no way to support bulk operations in the way you are looking for.

Taking a look here: https://github.com/onenotedev?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=sample&type=&language= I do not see any Java sample.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Even I didn't find any support for bulk operation. I will iterate over the pages and fetch individual page content.